# Почему односторонний рендеринг не выигрывает у рендеринга полигонов с двух сторон в Vulkan

Tags: render, vulkan

Учу Vulkan по гайду Vulkan Tutorial. Там в примере при создании пайплайна при указании растеризации cullMode стоит VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT и я заметил что из за этого если смотреть на полигоны с обратной стороны, что они не отображаются. Но есть поставить VK_CULL_MODE_NONE, то будет рисоваться с двух сторон. Но... если замерять время кадра с VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT и VK_CULL_MODE_NONE, то у меня оно получилось +- одинаковым на уровне погрешности. Как мне сказали на другом форуме "Вы рассуждаете как нормальный человек: ну меньше же полигонов рисуем, стало быть должно быть (ощутимо) быстрее. Неоднократно замечал что GPU этой логике не следует, и то что ожидается быстрее - рисуется медленнее, и наоборот." Так вот, почему это так не работает и производительность не увеличивается в +- 2 раза?

Answer (score 0):

Cullmode это как растеризатор будет отбрасывать вершины.
Есть куллинг по часовой, против часовой, а ещё его можно отключить.
Кулинг это очень простой и крайне эффективный способ оптимизировать отрисовку.
Вы рисуете сколько вершин? Предполагаю что у вас их немного. Попробуйте скачать где нить obj файл с кучей полигонов.

Comment: я обрисовываю около 3 млн полигонов. Это много или мало?

Comment: Вообще стоит найти что-нить побольше. Попробуйте миллионов 40 где-то.
Попробуйте в отладчике, например в https://renderdoc.org/ глянуть отсеклись ли вершины. 
надо убедиться что все настроенно как следует

Comment: И ещё, вы отрисовываете 3млн полигонов как? Это какой-то obj файлик или это просто набор треугольников?

Comment: Так-же рекомендую подключить разшерение, которое на окне рисует FPS. Не помню как называется, в enumerateInstacneExtension должно вернуться расширение которое имеет в названии слово display